# ArrayList<object> inside ArrayList<anotherObject> inside a class

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have 3 classes like this:

```
public class Subject {
    String name;
    ArrayList<Teacher> teachers;

    public Subject(String name, ArrayList<Teacher> teachers) {
        init();
        this.name = name;
        this.teachers = teachers;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Teacher> getTeachers() {
        return teachers;
    }

    public void setTeachers(ArrayList<Teacher> teachers) {
        this.teachers = teachers;
    }

    //
    private void init() {
        this.teachers = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}

public class Teacher {
    String name;
    ArrayList<DLink> dLinks;

    public Teacher(String name, ArrayList<DLink> dLinks) {
        init();
        this.name = name;
        this.dLinks = dLinks;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public ArrayList<DLink> getdLinks() {
        return dLinks;
    }

    public void setdLinks(ArrayList<DLink> dLinks) {
        this.dLinks = dLinks;
    }

    //
    private void init() {
        this.dLinks = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DLink {
    String URL;

    public DLink(String URL) {
        this.URL = URL;
    }

    public String getURL() {
        return URL;
    }

    public void setURL(String URL) {
        this.URL = URL;
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create some `ArrayList<Subject>` but I don't know how to do it. I tried to do like this:

```
ArrayList<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
subjects.add(new Subject("S1", new ArrayList<Teacher>().add(new Teacher("T1", new ArrayList<DLink>().add(new DLink("D1")))));
```

But I got syntax error. I want to know the correct syntax to manipulate Subject class's `objects` and how to add multiple values of `ArrayList<Teacher>`  & `ArrayList<DLink>` in a single line for Subject class's object.
Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ArrayList isn't a [builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). A builder is a class that returns itself in the methods so you can do stuff like:

```
new SomeClass().someField().someField().build()
```

and get an instance of `SomeClass` when it finally returns.

ArrayList **is not a builder**. This means the return values is not itself in every method.

When you do:

```
new ArrayList<SomeClass>();
```

You create a new ArrayList instance.

If you, however, do this:

```
new ArrayList<SomeClass>().add(new SomeClass());
```

That creates a new instance and then adds something to it. **However:**

The return value of `add` is `boolean`. Not `ArrayList`. Meaning when you call that method, there's a boolean returned, not an ArrayList. And when you stack it like that, it's similar to doing:

```
someINstance.getField()/*returns an instance of a class*/.someInteger/*now you grab an integer*/
```

In order to fix this you have to create the ArrayList separately:

```
ArrayList<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
List<Teacher> teachers = new ArrayList<>();
//then add to the ARrayList
List<DLink> dLinks = new ArrayList<DLink>();
dLinks.add(new DLink("D1"));
teachers.add(new Teacher("T1", dLinks);
subjects.add(new Subject("S1", teachers));
```

It's an extremely inefficient way of doing this tbh, but that's the only option when ArrayList (or any List for that matter) isn't a builder

**TL:DR;** Because ArrayList isn't a builder you don't get an instance of the List when you call `.add` meaning you have to have the instance separately, it can't be created and have values added instantly like you tried, because the method is a `boolean` meaning it doesn't return the instance of the ArrayList

---

A code example of what I'm trying to say:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int x = someMethod();
}

public static void someMethod(){
    System.out.println("whatever");
}
```

Same with ArrayLists. The first part gives you an instance, but then you get a void as return type meaning you don't get any instances from the final code.

---

And no, there is no way to do this in a single line, at least not in Java 8 and below.

Comment: Thank you so much for this amazing explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

When you type

```
subjects.add(new Subject("S1", new ArrayList<Teacher>().add(new Teacher("T1", new ArrayList<DLink>().add(new DLink("D1")))));
```

you are basically saying 'subjects.add(new Subject("S1", true), true)'
because you're not passing the reference to the array, you're passing the results of the add method which according to [java doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(E)) returns true if the add doesn't give any problem.

Try this instead:

```
ArrayList<Dlink> dlinkList = new ArrayList<>();
dlinkList.add("Test.url");

ArrayList<Teacher> teacherList = new ArrayList<>();
teacherList.add(new Teacher("Example name", dlinkList));

ArrayList<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();
subjects.add(new Subject("S1", teacherList);
```

Comment: Isn't there any way to do all these things in just one single line?

Comment: Not that i know, but even if it's possible i'll suggest you to be more clear as possible, this will save you time later.